# stackoverflow error at the beginning of the program in function main

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I made a program, I want to debug it (or run) and before the first operator in function main it breaks with a message: Unhandled exception at 0x0020f677 in name.exe: Stack overflow.
Why is this happening and how to resolve the problem?
Visual C++ 2010, Win32 console application.

EDIT1:
Debugger shows me the asm code at chkstk.asm.

What is important to analyse in order to solve this problem? Something added in header files is causing this problem?

Comment: You have global variables? If you can post the code a definitive answer can be provided.

Comment: No I don't have global variables, but have some additional header files, the code is litle bit inconvenient to paste here because I have about 5 header files..

Comment: Do your header files contain global variables?

Comment: No, they don't contain global variables

Comment: +1 for using the term stackoverflow in its context ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you decleared a fixed size array and if its size is too much, you may have this error.

```
int fixedarray[1000000000];
```

Try to decrease the length or create it on the heap.

```
int * array = new int[1000000000];
```

Do not forget to delete it later.

```
delete[] array;
```

But it is better to use std::vector instead of pointers even in a C function,

```
//...
int Old_C_Func(int * ptrs, unsigned len_);
//...
std::vector<int> intvec(1000000000);
int * intptr = &intvec[0];
int result = Old_C_Func(intptr,intvec.size());
```

assuming 32bit compilation.

Comment: just FYI for readers) by default, stack size is 1MB in Windows and it would be bigger in Linux like 8MB (we can change the size though). So, the OP might have declared a fixed sized array larger than ~1MB since he/she is using Windows.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an object constructor or some code triggered by one is causing a stack overflow.  I'd use the debugger to see what the stack overflow is being caused by, keeping in mind that a constructor for a global variable might be the root cause.

Comment: Can you backtrace so that you know more than that, or is that as far down as the debugger will take you?

Comment: first it shows some calls to kernel and ntdll.
and the goes call to mainCRTStartUp
then __tmainCRTStartup()
and finally _chkstk()

Answer (score 0):

If the stackoverflow error is caused by deep recursion or by big objects on stack, you can also solve it by increasing stack size. Default size for stack on Windows 1MB. You can try to increase it for example to 10MB

Add following line to Project property -> Linker -> Command line

/STACK:1000000,1000000

If the bug is caused by some mistake in algorithm recursion, increasing stack size does not help and you need to find the bug (probably in recursion) or extremely large stack allocation.

Comment: The stack reserve and commit sizes are actually defined under Linker -> System

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, no debug info, no globals, no oversized arrays.

I had a class with some structs which were #pragma_pack-ed, and if I construct this class in the stack, then this error occured. If I allocate it on the heap, runs fine.
( any ideas why? )